# Server not receiving Client message

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am trying to create a server-client program where 2 clients can send messages to each other just like how one would chat in facebook. I was able to go up to the point where multiple clients can connect to the server but it seems like i fail to find a way for the server to receive any messages from a client.

Heres my code so far:

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <list>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
#define PORTNUM 5001
#define MAXPARTICIPANTS 10

using namespace std;

int sockfd = 0;
int connfd = 0;
int clients[MAXPARTICIPANTS] = {};
bool dupe;
int receiver = 0;


struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
char sendBuff[BUFFERSIZE];
char receiveBuff[BUFFERSIZE];

void *getNewParticipant(void *arg){
    while (1){
        dupe = false;
        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        for(int i=0; i<MAXPARTICIPANTS; i++){
            if(clients[i] == connfd){
                dupe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!dupe){
            for(int i=0; i<MAXPARTICIPANTS; i++){
                if(clients[i] == 0){
                    clients[i] = connfd;
                    cout << connfd << " joined" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<MAXPARTICIPANTS; i++){
                cout << clients[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            sprintf(sendBuff, "%d joined the conversation", connfd);
            for(int i=0; i<MAXPARTICIPANTS; i++){
                if(clients[i] != 0){
                    write(clients[i], sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
                }
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void *handleMessages(void *arg){
    while(1){
        if((receiver = read(sockfd, receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff)-1)) > 0){
            receiveBuff[receiver] = 0;
            if(fputs(receiveBuff, stdout) == EOF){
                cout << "ERROR" << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        /*int receiver = recv(sockfd, receiveBuff, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
         //if(receiver > 0){
         cout << receiver << ": " << receiveBuff << endl;
         for(int i=0; i<MAXPARTICIPANTS; i++){
         if(clients[i] != 0){
         write(clients[i], receiveBuff, strlen(receiveBuff));
         }
         }
         //}*/
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void){

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        cout << "Failed to create Socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0){
        cout << "Failed to bind socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Setup complete. Waiting for clients...." << endl;

    if(listen(sockfd, MAXPARTICIPANTS) < 0){
        cout << "Failed to Listen" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_t tid[2];
    pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, getNewParticipant, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, handleMessages, NULL);

    while (1) {

    }
}
```

Client

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
#define PORTNUM 5001

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sockfd = 0, connfd = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    char recvBuff[BUFFERSIZE];
    char sendBuff[BUFFERSIZE];
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        cout << "Failed to create Socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) ) <0){
        cout << "Failed to connect" << endl;
    }

    while(1){
        if((connfd = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0){
            recvBuff[connfd] = 0;
            if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF){
                cout << "Error" << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "input: " << endl;
        do{
            cin.getline(sendBuff, BUFFERSIZE);
            cout<< "input: " << sendBuff << endl;
            if(strlen(sendBuff) > 0){
                write(sockfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
                //send(sockfd, sendBuff, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
                cout << "sent" << endl;
            }
        }while (*sendBuff != 42);


        sleep(1);
    }

}
```

Please tell me what the cause of the problem is, and how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: You must read from the socket descriptor which returns from the accept() call , but you are trying to read from the actual listener socket.

Comment: It may still not work because you don't have ( or i can't see ) any synchronization between your threads. By the time your [handleMessages] thread starts, the client handler socket (variable named "connfd" ) which you will use to receive data  will be null, because you start both threads at the same time. I may be wrong though, because i'm not an expert on Linux threads.